# Problems with new thread in gui

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, sudoku

I have a problem with threads... I manage to start the thread and the program does what it is supposed to, but it does not start til the main painting i the gui has started.
So here it my code;

```
public void getFile() {
    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            viewTimeBar();
        }
    };

    try {
        JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
        int returnVal = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(this);
        if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            runSudoku = new RunSudoku(fileChooser.getSelectedFile().getName(), 0);
        }
        if(runSudoku.boardSize > 8) {
            r.run();
        }
        runSudoku.runBoard();

        printBoard(runSudoku.sudokuBoard, 0);
        getNextSolution.setText("Solutions: " + (runSudoku.validBoards.size()) + ", press get solution");
        getSolution.setEnabled(true);

    } catch(Exception e) {
        printError();
    }
}

public void viewTimeBar() {
    if(sudokuPanel != null) {
       remove(sudokuPanel);
    }

    JPanel timer = new JPanel();
    JLabel pleaseWait = new JLabel("Please wait while we try to find solutions!", SwingConstants.CENTER);
    timer.add(pleaseWait, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    JProgressBar progressBar = new JProgressBar();
    progressBar.setSize(10, 400);
    progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
    progressBar.setStringPainted(true);
    timer.add(progressBar, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    timer.setVisible(true);
    add(timer, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    validate();
}
```

The runnable shoud start viewTimeBar if board size is bigger than 8, but it does not paint til printBoard method runs.

Anyone who can help me out?

Kind regards, Henning

Comment: `Runnable#run()` is a regular method. If you call it like a normal method you get a normal method, i.e. code executed sequentially in your current thread.

Comment: What do you mean with Runnable#run() ? Currently the method is called with r.run(), where r is a runnable.. Actually, when i tested now the method will not run if i use runnable or just the usual method call to viewTimeBar...

Comment: he says Runnable#run() to indicate the method signature.

Answer (score 1):

Even if it is a r is a `Runnable`,the `run()` method is just a normal method. You need to start a thread which will execute your runnable.

Replace

```
    if(runSudoku.boardSize > 8) {
        r.run();
    }
```

by

```
    if(runSudoku.boardSize > 8) {
        new Thread(r).start();
    }
```

Comment: Yeh, that was smart! Program is still not updating the way it should... The viewTimeBar runs with printBoard :/

Comment: In the context of Swing programming, this is bad advice - SWING IS NOT THREADSAFE! Either use `SwingWorker` or `SwingUtilities.invokeLater`

Comment: I have not used these tools before. Could you show me? The program should work like this; get file -> if(board size > 8) the progress bar should show -> progress bar should dissapear and then print board

Comment: See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html for some guidance on using the `SwingWorker` class.